# Why do I get "Invalid predicate" error from getElementsByTagName?

Tags: xml, perl

I have the following XML:

```
<config>
  <version general="1.2.3">
    <subtype type="a" version="1.2" />
    <subtype type="b" version="3.6" />
    ...
  </version>
  ...
</config>
```

I have some code in Perl to get the config node from a database.

After I get it, if I try the following:

```
my $elem = $cfg->getElementsByTagName("version");
my $generalVer = $elem ? $elem->get_node(1)->getAttribute("general") : undef;
```

all works fine, `$generalVer` contains `1.2.3`, as expected.

But if I try this:

```
my $elem = $cfg->getElementsByTagName("version/subtype[@type='a']");
my $aVersion = $elem ? $elem->get_node(1)->getAttribute("version") : undef;
```

It fails with the message "Invalid predicate".

Can someone help with this issue?

Comment: what XML library are you using ?

Comment: A small, complete program showing the problem would be very helpful. I suspect, just looking at what you have, that 'use warnings' would tell you exactly what's wrong. :)

Comment: I use XML::LibXML. Should have mentioned it. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks everybody for the answers.

Short time after I asked the question, someone answered that the problem was the single quote and if I'll use double quotes it would work. i.e. `@type=`**"**`a`**"** instead of `@type=`**'**`a`**'**.

Well, this indeed solved it. But when I tried to mark his answer as the correct answer I found out that he deleted it.

So I'm posting the answer myself, just for the record.

The following code works just fine:

```
my $elem = $cfg->getElementsByTagName("version/subtype[@type=\"a\"]");
my $aVersion = $elem ? $elem->get_node(1)->getAttribute("version") : undef;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Nope, my xpath works just fine when I use single quote

Answer (score 10):

I strongly suspect that `"version/subtype[@type='a']"` is not, in fact, a tag name. That looks like an XPath query.

I'm assuming you're using something like [XML::DOM](http://search.cpan.org/~tjmather/XML-DOM/lib/XML/DOM.pm) to parse this XML. If you want to use XPath, then you can use [XML::DOM::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-DOM-XPath/XPath.pm), which adds XPath support.

For example,

```
 use XML::DOM;
 use XML::DOM::XPath;
 ...
 my $elem = $cfg->findnodes( q{//version/subtype[@type='a']} );
```

Comment: I suspect you want to single quote that argument. :)

Answer (score 4):

The `getElementsByTagName` method expects a name, I don't think it supports XPath.  To use XPath queries, you'd have to use a module like XML::XPath instead of XML::DOM.

Here's an example using XML::XPath:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::XPath;

my $xml = <<END;
<config>
  <version general="1.2.3">
    <subtype type="a" version="1.2" />
    <subtype type="b" version="3.6" />
  </version>
</config>
END

my $xp = XML::XPath->new(xml => $xml);
my $nodeset = $xp->find("//version/subtype[\@type='a']");
foreach my $node ($nodeset->get_nodelist) {
    my $version = $node->getAttribute("version");
    print "Version: $version\n";
}
```

Note that you have to escape the `@` in `subtype[\@type='a'`, otherwise Perl will be looking for an array called `@type`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use XPath to pick out your element with a path or do it in two steps. getElementsByTagName() can only handle tag names - not paths to elements. XPath is preferred when you do conditional selects, though (which you are with "@type='a'").