# how to write the simple short code for parsing

Tags: php

I'm working on my PHP to get the list of time. I'm using DomDocument to get the time, I want to find a way to reduce the code as I have got the 69 tags of time in my get-listing.php script.

if I use this:

```
$time1 = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time1']");
$time2 = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time2']");
$time3 = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time3']");
$time4 = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time4']");
$time5 = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time5']");
$time6 = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time6']");
$time7 = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time7']");
...etc until to get time69

$time69 = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time69']");
```

It will be too large for me to write the list of code to parsing the time from the time1 tag to time69 tag.

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;

function getState($string)
{
  $ex = explode(" ",$string);
  return $ex[1];
}

$xml .= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
$xml .= '
<tv generator-info-name="www.mysite.com/xmltv">';
$baseUrl = file_get_contents('http://www.mysite.com/get-listing.php');

$domdoc = new DOMDocument();
$domdoc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$domdoc->recover=true;
//@$domdoc->loadHTMLFile($baseUrl);
@$domdoc->loadHTML($baseUrl);
$links = $domdoc->getElementsByTagName('a');
$i = 0;
$count = 0;

$data = array();
foreach($links as $link)
{  
  //echo $domdoc->saveXML($link);
  if($link->getAttribute('href'))
  {
     if(!$link->hasAttribute('id') || $link->getAttribute('id')!='streams')
     {
       $url = str_replace("rtmp://", "", $link->getAttribute('href'));
       $url = str_replace(" ", "%20", $link->getAttribute('href'));
       //echo $url;
       //echo "<br>";
       $sdoc = new DOMDocument();
       $sdoc->strictErrorChecking = false;
       $sdoc->recover=true;
       @$sdoc->loadHTMLFile($url);
       $time1_span = $sdoc->getElementById('time1');       
       //$spans = $sdoc->getElementsByTagName('time1');
       $query = parse_url($url)['query'];
       $channel_split = explode("&", $query)[0];
       $channel = urldecode(explode("=",$channel_split)[1]);
       $id_split = explode("&", $query)[1];
       $my_id = urldecode(explode("=",$id_split)[1]);
       $xpath = new DOMXpath($sdoc);
       $time1 = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time1']");
       $time2 = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time2']");
       $time3 = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time3']");
       //$time4 = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time4']");

       $array = array(
         $time1,$time2,$time3
       );

       // Save the output format
       $DATE_FORMAT_STRING = "YmdHis";

       // GET the current STAGE
       $current_state = getState($array[0]->nodeValue);
       $offset = 0;
       $flag = 0;

       foreach($array as $time)
       {
         echo $time->item(0)->nodeValue;
         // Get the item state.  
         //$this_state = getState($time);
         $this_state = getState($time->item(0)->nodeValue);
         //echo $time->nodeValue;

         // check if we past a day? 
         if($current_state == "PM" && $this_state == "AM")
         {
           $offset++;
         }
         $this_unix = strtotime($time->item(0)->nodeValue) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);
         $values[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix);
         //echo date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix);
         echo $values[$count];
         echo "<br></br>";

         $starttime = $times->nodeValue;
         //echo $starttime;
         echo "<programme channel='".$my_id." ".$channel." start='".$starttime."' stop='".$stoptime."'>";

     /*if($flag>0)
     {
       //echo "<programme channel='".$my_id." ".$channel." start='".$starttime."' stop='".$stoptime."'>";
       $stoptime = $starttime;
       $flag=1;
     }
     else
     {
       $stoptime = $starttime;
     }*/ 
         $current_state = $this_state;
         $count++;
       }         
     }
  }
}
?>
```

My question is how do you write the simple way to write the code to make it shorter to get the element id of time1 to time69 using with few line of code?

Edit: I'm getting fatal error when I'm trying to print the list of strings.

The error are jumping on this line:

```
$time{$i} = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time".$i."']");
```

It could be this:

```
echo $time->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array in /home/myusername/public_html/work_on_this.php on line 57

Here is the update code:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 70; $i++) 
       {
         $time{$i} = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time".$i."']");

         $array = array(
           $time{$i}
         );

         foreach($array as $time)
         {
           echo $time->item(0)->nodeValue;
         }
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the code to following,

```
$time_arr = array();
for ($i = 1; $i < 70; $i++){
   $time_arr[] = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time".$i."']");
}

foreach($time_arr as $time){
   echo $time->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

I'm adding the values to an array directly in the for loop instead of assigning them separately.

And also foreach should not be within for loop which gets the time value.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can see it is working now. Cheers for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 70; $i++) {
    $time{$i} = $xpath->query("*/span[@id = \"time\" . $i]");
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for this, but there is a problem. I have got an error `Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid predicate` which is jumping on this line: `$time{$i} = $xpath->query("*/span[@id = 'time' . $i]");`. do you know why I'm getting an error?

Comment: Try using double quotes for 'time' (instead of single quotes)....see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965879/why-do-i-get-invalid-predicate-error-from-getelementsbytagname

Comment: hope it should be `$time{$i} = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time$i']");` or to give clarity `$time{$i} = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time".$i."']");`

Comment: @Lepanto thank you very much for this. when I'm trying to print to get the list of strings, I will get an error like this: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array` when using `echo $time->item(0)->nodeValue;`. Please see my update on my first post.